# Unity2D: Pushing Player away on collision with enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add a script to my game so that whenever the player collides with an enemy he takes damage but is also pushed away in opposite direction. I have tried implementing the Rigidbody2D extension code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34250868/unity-addexplosionforce-to-2d)

Here is part of my player script:

```cs
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        var magnitude = 5000;
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Monster"))
        {
            TakeDamage(25);
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddExplosionForce(magnitude, this.transform.position, 500);
        }
    }
```

When I run the game in Unity I get this error whenever the player collides with an enemy:

```
Rigidbody2D.AddForce(force) assign attempt for 'Player' is not valid. Input force is { NaN, NaN }.
UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D:AddForce(Vector2, ForceMode2D)
Rigidbody2DExt:AddExplosionForce(Rigidbody2D, Single, Vector2, Single, Single, ForceMode2D) (at Assets/Scripts/Rigidbody2DExt.cs:20)
Player:OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D) (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:94)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

I would recommend you to try with:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){

    Vector2 impulse = new Vector2(-7, 2);
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Monster")){
        TakeDamage(25);
        GetComponent<RigidBody2D>().AddForce(impulse, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

}
```

Also you have to find a way to get the desired direction to push the player. For example, if you approach the enemy from the right, you may want to be pushed to the left. In my example, you will be pushed to the left with some up impulse. Let me know if you still have problems :)

References [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've just added this to my script, I don't get any errors but nothing happens when the player collides with the monster. I've tried increasing the magnitude of Vector2 impulse but there's still no effect. On both the player and the monster I have a Rigidbody2D (with Is trigger unticked) and a box collider

Comment: Do you reset the velocity of the player frequently? Maybe the impulse is applied but you change the velocity to 0,0 (for movement, for example)

Comment: Yeah...that might be it, I have my movement controls in FixedUpdate():
float moveX = 0;
float moveY = 0;
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) moveX += 1;
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) moveX -= 1;
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) moveY += 1;
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) moveY -= 1;
Vector2 newVelocity = new Vector2(moveX, moveY).normalized * PLAYER_SPEED;

Comment: Yes, I think thats the problem. Maybe you can delay the movement during 0.5/0.6 seconds when you are hitted, so you can't use the controls. But I recommend you not to reset the velocity each frame, if you don't want to go fast just clamp the velocity values. Hope it works

Comment: Yup, I've disabled player movement in the FixedUpdate() and it works. So now I just have to find a way to implement movement controls without reseting the velocity